# How to access a shared host website with it's IP and domain header in a browser

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, browser, bypass

The problem:
My client DNS settings are such that I can't access sites after certain hours, so I use a VPN to keep operating normally; however, some sites (unfortunately the only ones I know of so far) like okcupid.com and POF.com can be accessed but break down and cease to function when dealing with any authentication. This prevents login attempts or account creation.
It could just be a captcha plugin malfunctioning, but it could also likely be the site itself.

Possible/preferred solution:
It seems that the best way to bypass both DNS and my VPN to get direct access to the site would be to access it with a combination of its IP and a header with the domain; within a browser, if that's possible. But I have no idea how I'd send both the IP and a header at the same time within a browser.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set the DNS name of the site into your hosts file with the public IP to not require DNS resolving at all.

See instructions from here: https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/modify-your-hosts-file/